# keep android button selected state

Tags: android, button

I know this is a question that has been asked many times before, but I can't seem to solve it in my code. I have two buttons, and when one is pressed, I would like to keep it in its selected state, and vice versa. I have tried doing it using but the setSelected and setPressed, but I can't seem to get it to work. Here is the code I am using:

```
    region_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            objects = category;
            adap.notifyDataSetChanged();
            proximity_button.setPressed(false);
            region_button.setPressed(true);

        }
    });

    proximity_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            objects = proximity;
            adap.notifyDataSetChanged();
            region_button.setPressed(false);
            proximity_button.setPressed(true);

        }
    });
```

**Edit:**
Based on the comments, I need to add that I have a custom xml background for the buttons, and would like to retain the current look.

Comment: Why don't you just use RadioGroup and RadioButton, then set right attributes to your RadioButtons, using a selector it should do the trick !

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I searched on Google and found this Stack Overflow post:
[How can i keep one button as pressed after click on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747311/how-can-i-keep-one-button-as-pressed-after-click-on-it)

```
mycodes_Button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        mycodes_Button.setPressed(true);
        return true;
    }
});
```

But read the comment, it's pretty interesting!

Comment: Almost right-just for other's reference, the other button state also needs to be set to false, but I'll accept anyhow because it got me on the right track. Thanks!

Comment: using setSelected (http://stackoverflow.com/a/3417158/667834) worked better for me so I could still have functionality on release

Answer (score 4):

Why are you using Buttons? [CheckBox](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html) or [RadioGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html) is best solution for these case

```
checkBox.setChecked(false);
```

Comment: Not if you don't like the UI of check boxes.

Comment: You could change it to whatever you want

Comment: Depending on the needs, yes you could.

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm late to the party but I tried doing the above and it was still acting like a temporary state (unless you want to keep your finger on it).

What worked for me is to have `state_selected="true"` in the **XML** file + `imageButton.setSelected(true)` in my java file. see below.

```
ibType1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    ibType1.setSelected(true);
    ibType2.setSelected(false);
}//onClick
});
```

XML:

```
<item android:state_selected="true">
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="45dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000"/>
</shape>
```

This will allow you to have image buttons or button with a specific background state selected programmatically up until you decide to selected another image button or button.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a thought, disable the pressed button and enable the others. Have the disabled button layout similar to the pressed layout. The user will see it as pressed, but it's actually disabled.

Answer (score 0):

A checkbox could work, but if you're after a UI closer `UISegmentedControl` on iOS, which is possible wrapping all the buttons needed in a `LinearLayout`, then you could do something along the lines of:

```
public void onClick( View v ){
    if ( v.getID == R.id.btn1 ) {
        btn1.setEnabled(false);
        btn2.setEnabled(true);
        // do stuff
    }
    else if ( v.getId() == R.id.btn2 ) {
        btn2.setEnabled(false);
        btn1.setEnabled(true);
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Of course, in your drawable folder, you would add background colour, borders, and other visual stuff for each state.

Comment: I am looking for a look similar to NSSegmentedControl on iOS, but the problem with your solution, is once a button is not enabled, clicking on it again will do nothing.

Comment: @coder That's the idea behind UIsegmentedControl (my bad earlier for the typo).  To re-enable a disabled button, another one needs to be pressed.  It functions exactly like a radio group.