# How to put a button in pressed state in android

Tags: android, button, android-widget

My problem is similar to question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747311/how-can-i-keep-one-button-as-pressed-after-click-on-it). I want an Android button to stay pressed. I cannot follow the solution provided because `onClick` will be called when a button is pressed via keyboard or trackball and i need to handle that.

I tried setting `button.setPressed(true);` in `onClick` callback , but it doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sending a touch event to the button like this:

```
MotionEvent down = MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 0, 0, 0);
yourButton.dispatchTouchEvent(down);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this it will work...

```
singIn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) return true;
                    if(event.getAction()!=MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) return false;

                  //DO SOMETHING!!

                    singIn.setPressed(true);                    
                    return true;
                }


            });
```