# Disabled button loses pressed state when touched

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener

I'm generating a number of buttons programmatically (some to increase a value while others to decrease a value) that I disable when the value they adjust either reaches a maximum or minimum. (i.e. The 'increase' button is disabled when the maximum is reached while the 'decrease' button is disabled when the minimum is reached.) In addition to disabling, I'm also setting the button state to 'pressed' in order to visually indicate that the limit value has been reached and the button no longer functions.

My button onClickListener for the 'increase' buttons look like this:

```
increase.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // do some stuff

        // here I enable the corresponding 'decrease' button because once you increase you can then decrease
        setEnabled(decrease, true);

        // if the maximum value is obtained, I disable the 'increase' button because you can't go higher
        if (value == maximum) {
            setEnabled(increase, false);
        }
    }
});
```

The corresponding 'decrease' onClickListeners are similar.

Because these button are changing their own state, I need to use a `Handler` to adjust `Button.setEnabled()` and `Button.setPressed()` after a small delay, so that the user's finger doesn't get in the way (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/28788780/852795). Here is the `setEnabled(final Button b, final boolean set)` method that is used above:

```
private void setEnabled(final Button b, final boolean set) {
    Handler refresh = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    refresh.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            b.setEnabled(set);
            b.setPressed(!set);
        }
    }, 250); // delayed post required to make pressed button accept setPressed()
}
```

Everything works great, with one small exception: once a user presses the 'increase' button enough times to reach the maximum the button will be disabled and the 'pressed' state will be set to true, however, if it's then pressed one more time, the 'pressed' state will be turned off. Functionally, the button is disabled. I know this because the onClickHandler is not invoked. Why then is my button losing it's 'pressed' state? How can I stop this from happening?

**Update**: Looking at https://stackoverflow.com/a/8693444/852795 I tried plugging into the `onTouchListener()` in order to 'intercept' the touch that's turning off the pressed state. However, this, too, is not invoked because, I would imagine, the button is disabled.

Comment: I don't think you can use the pressed state when the button is disabled.

Comment: A more reliable way to handle this might be to change your button background to a StateListDrawable with its 'disabled' state set the same as its 'pressed' state. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Comment: The button is disabled and the pressed state is set to 'true', which all works fine. If it is then pressed again (while disabled!), the pressed state gets turned off.

Comment: Try overriding the OnTouchListener for the button and don't call super.onTouch if the button is disabled

Comment: @Egg The StateListDrawable is the answer. Adding `<item android:drawable="@drawable/overlay_button_pressed" android:state_enabled="false"/>` to my button selector was all I needed. A 1-line fix! Feel free to post the answer to claim your prize. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to handle this would be to use a StateListDrawable as the background of the button and set the Disabled state to use the same drawable as the Pressed state. This way you could avoid having to set the Pressed state in code.

ie

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_pressed"/> <!-- disabled (same as pressed) -->
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_normal"/>
</selector>
```